# Почему не воспроизвоться блок кода aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Даю участок кода, который не воспроизводиться при попытке сделать это.

```
@dp.message_handler(Text(equals='Ноутбуки', ignore_case=True), state=PriceState.parser)
@dp.message_handler(commands=['laptops'], state=PriceState.parser)
async def parsing_laptops(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    data = await state.get_data()
    url = 'https://www.kufar.by/l/r~vitebsk/noutbuki'
    params = {'prc': f'r%3A{data["min_price"]*100}%2C{data["max_price"]*100}', 'sort': 'lst.d'}
    with requests.get(url, params=params) as r:
        b = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    i = 0
    for section in b.find_all('section'):
        price = str(section.span.text)
        title = str(section.find('h3', {'class': 'styles_title__ARIVF'}).text)
        city = str(section.find('div', {'class': 'styles_secondary__NEYhw'}).p.text)
        url = str(section.find('a', {'class': 'styles_wrapper__yaLfq'})['href'])
        url_photo = section.find('img', {'class': 'styles_image__eGgZr lazyload'})['data-src']
        caption = f'Название: {title}\nГород: {city}\nЦена: {price}\nСсылка на объявление: {url}'
        await message.answer_photo(photo=url_photo, caption=caption)
```

Прикладываю фото, как пытался вызвать команды[image: попытка вызвать блок кода]

Answer (score 0):

может это сработает?:

```
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Text
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

bot = Bot(token='YOUR_TELEGRAM_TOKEN')
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=MemoryStorage())


@dp.message_handler(Text(equals='Ноутбуки', ignore_case=True), state=PriceState.parser)
@dp.message_handler(commands=['laptops'], state=PriceState.parser)
async def parsing_laptops(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    data = await state.get_data()
    url = 'https://www.kufar.by/l/r~vitebsk/noutbuki'
    params = {'prc': f'r%3A{data["min_price"]*100}%2C{data["max_price"]*100}', 'sort': 'lst.d'}
    r = requests.get(url, params=params)
    b = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    i = 0
    for section in b.find_all('section'):
        price = str(section.span.text)
        title = str(section.find('h3', {'class': 'styles_title__ARIVF'}).text)
        city = str(section.find('div', {'class': 'styles_secondary__NEYhw'}).p.text)
        url = str(section.find('a', {'class': 'styles_wrapper__yaLfq'})['href'])
        url_photo = section.find('img', {'class': 'styles_image__eGgZr lazyload'})['data-src']
        caption = f'Название: {title}\nГород: {city}\nЦена: {price}\nСсылка на объявление: {url}'
        await message.answer_photo(photo=url_photo, caption=caption)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from aiogram import executor
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).